# Is there a way to kill explorer.exe and then run a batch file that starts it again?

Tags: windows-7, batch

Could this be done in batch or even in virtual basic?

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /t /f & start bat.bat
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Ending the entire Explorer.exe process tree causes all programs to exit - including your script. This is why your call to bat.bat never executes. If you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish by killing explorer.exe and restarting it, we might be able to offer additional advice.

Comment: @Tyler What gave you the idea programs close if you exit Explorer.exe? Explorer.exe only closes all file explorer windows, and vanishes the taskbar. Other processes remain active, so launching a script would start a command prompt window, that would remain active, so yes, you can do this in a script. Just put it on 2 rows, not use &

Comment: @LPChip This is what I noticed when trying to find a solution on my computer. I have to relaunch all previously running apps if I kill explorer.exe with the /t option. Your script below also fails on my computer, but for different reasons without the /t option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a batch file.

Just write them as if you are typing it in a commandprompt window.

So your bat.bat would look like this:

```
:: stop explorer and wait with executing the next bit
start "" "taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f" /wait

:: start it again
start "" explorer.exe /wait
```

`::` is the same as `REM` btw. You can ommit it in your script.

If you want to restart your explorer, just run the bat.bat file.

Comment: I put this in a batch file called kill.bat and get the error "Windows cannot find 'taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again." If I change the first line to `start /wait taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f`, the batch file correctly kills explorer.exe, but the second line of code launches an explorer window instead of re-launching the task bar.

Comment: @tyler: it runs fine on my computer. If it doesn't on yours, you may not have set the system32 folder in your path environment. Replace taskkill with c:\windows\system32\taskkill and it will work on your computer too.

Comment: taskkill is in my PATH. It works if I change the command to: `start /wait taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f`. I get the error noted previously if I use `start "" "taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f" /wait`

Comment: Odd... well if that works for you, then use that. I tested this on my machine and it works here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a batch file,
The restart.bat would look this:

`taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`