# Way to remember/ retain recall & restart Explorer Windows/ Folders with folder paths intact? Esp if/when frozen/ stuck or hang in Not Responding mode?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, freeze

Way to restart Explorer Windows when they are frozen/ stuck in Not Responding mode?

Typically I can do an End Task/ Restart/ New Task from Task Manager and the easy answer is ending/ restarting them. **But, I want all the relevant Windows Explorer windows remembered and opened again.**

**I want to reopen all the Explorer windows with those Folder/ Explorer Paths as they were before they freeze and were killed/ restart.**

**A lot of time I have freezes or crashes and at times simple reboots where I'd like to keep the "existing explorer windows" upon restart for visual mental workspace flow recall.**

Is there a smart/ quick/ auto or semi-auto way to do that when faced with Not Responding Explorer windows?

I face this several times during usage (for various reasons I am guessing from low memory to slow drive or slow apps or plain wierdness) or at times when Restarting (have the Restore windows enabled).

The following "how tos" do not address the additional requirement.

Currently on Win 8.1 x64 and intend to stay away from Win 10 as long as possible.

- [Is there a way to kill explorer.exe and then run a batch file that starts it again?](https://superuser.com/questions/875014/is-there-a-way-to-kill-explorer-exe-and-then-run-a-batch-file-that-starts-it-aga)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954041/restarting-explorer-exe-only-opens-an-explorer-window

Comment: *"I face this (problem) several times during usage..."*  If that's true, your system has some serious issues.  However, you also said *"Currently on Win 8.1 x64 and intend to stay away from Win 10 as long as possible."*  The vast majority of IT professionals that I know prefer Windows 10 over Windows 8.1, but beyond your personal preferences have you considered the possibility that installing Windows 10 will alleviate your persistent Explorer problems?

Comment: @Run5k - This is not a regular feature but bugs me once in a while. And its not something that did not happen in Win 95, 98, 2000, XP, and so in in 10 too. It's just how Windows is and sometimes Explorer windows freeze when system is overloaded.

Comment: Command: `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer & explorer <folder_path>`

Comment: You specifically said that you *"face this several times during usage."*  I have had a full-time job maintaining at least three Windows domains with over 10,000 workstations for over 20 years, and based upon my experience I can safely say that having Explorer frozen is definitely not *"just how Windows is."*  It only occurs when there is something overtly wrong with that specific operating system build.

Comment: @Biswa - Will it automatically save all those folder paths? When its freezing I have no way to get the paths. Is there anyway to have get, save and reopen the paths?

Comment: @AlexS you've to manually remember and enter the folder path in that batch file.

Comment: As Biswa already implied, there really isn't a method to "remember" the folder paths for each Explorer window.  Ultimately, you will need to actually address the root cause of the problem, rather than repeatedly dealing with the symptoms.  This is absolutely **not** *"just how Windows is,"* it is unusual and should be alleviated without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to keep a lot "explorer windows folders and sessions" active for usage and easy jump & accessibility to folder and workspaces; mentally and digitally.

Since I was never able to do this with Windows Explorer/ File Manager directly I started looking at and using some alternative file managers and eventually stumbled upon the following tools that in **different ways facilitate the need I had associated with this question and the technical shortcoming that existed**.

Its likely that the following leverage WE or FE internally or via some API, but it does circumvent the issue I was facing.

- [Tabaculus Explorer](https://tablacus.github.io/explorer_en.html) - Allows upto 9 (6, 8 etc.) Split Window Pane sections via its own extensible framework of add-ons ([1](https://tablacus.github.io/wiki/addons/), [2](https://tablacus.github.io/TablacusExplorerAddons/)) with each Pane allowing multiple tabs. I can work on whatever and wherever and when I close and reopen it it remembers all the locations & explorer sessions.

(I am thankful to a commenter on on some site mention it compared to Q-Dir)

[image]

- [Q-Dir](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir) - Similar as above allows 4 split panes and probably been more popular / well known and around longer compared to Tabaculus.

Unable to embed the images for some reason:
https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir/Screenshots

- [Direct Folders](https://www.codesector.com/directfolders): Code Sector is more known for its TeraCopy application to add more function to Copying space. Direct folders allows for easier access to lots of folders/ paths via File Dialog Boxes and opening Windows Explorer sessions as needed. I am sure there are others like it but it has a free version and works easy.

Answer (score 0):

simply open Taskmanager, kill `explorer.exe`. Then in taskmanager: File -> new task, type `explorer`

Comment: I can do that already and have linked on how I can do that with batch too. I want to reopen all the Explorer windows with those Folder/ Explorer Paths as they were before they freeze and were killed.